# Replace Finder with Forklift

Tags: finder

Is possible to have [Forklift](http://www.binarynights.com/) open folders, paths, etc instead of Finder?

Comment: quitting the Finder will also disable the desktop :-(

Answer (score 3):

Discussion [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5685/is-it-possible-to-run-nautilus-on-os-x) on replacing `Finder` with `nautilus`.

You can add a Quit menu item to Finder and quit it like so:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder QuitMenuItem 1; killall Finder
```

Now, run ForkLift.

You could try (WARNING: DANGEROUS) to rename ForkLift2.app as Finder.app and replace Finder.app, but I think this would probably just cause problems, possibly severe ones.

What do you mean by "open folders, paths, etc."? Almost all Finder interactions on my computer are initiated by me. Just use ForkLift instead. The only time something else uses Finder is if I double-click on a DMG, then it opens in Finder. If you have this, or other specific use cases that you would like to have interact with ForkLift, please clarify or post additional specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

Add these to your `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`

```
{   LSHandlerContentType = "public.folder";
    LSHandlerRoleAll = "com.binarynights.ForkLift-3";
}
```

Then reboot.

BTW, this answer to [Set ForkLift as default file viewer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45831) may also work.

Answer (score 2):

The [official site](https://binarynights.com/manual#fileviewer) now suggests:

```bsh
defaults write -g NSFileViewer -string com.binarynights.ForkLift-3;
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType="public.folder";LSHandlerRoleAll="com.binarynights.ForkLift-3";}'
```

While for the SetApp version:

```bsh
defaults write -g NSFileViewer -string com.binarynights.forklift-setapp;
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType="public.folder";LSHandlerRoleAll="com.binarynights.forklift-setapp";}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change default file manager like this, but ForkLift or Transmit not work as expected, only Path Finder are

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6

from LaunchServices import LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType, kLSRolesViewer, LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme
from CoreFoundation import CFPreferencesCopyApplicationList, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost, CFPreferencesSetAppValue, CFPreferencesAppSynchronize

applicationBundleIdentifier = "com.cocoatech.PathFinder" #"com.panic.Transmit" #"com.binarynights.forklift2"

LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType("public.folder", kLSRolesViewer, applicationBundleIdentifier)
LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme("file:///", applicationBundleIdentifier)

applicationIDs = CFPreferencesCopyApplicationList(kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost)
for app_id in applicationIDs:
    CFPreferencesSetAppValue("NSFileViewer", applicationBundleIdentifier, app_id);
    CFPreferencesAppSynchronize(app_id);
```