# How to make a HTML file as your wall paper

Tags: macos

Is there any way to use a Web arrive file or a HTML file as your wall paper? I found this interactive website (http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/css3d_periodictable.html) and want to put it as my wall paper.

Comment: Your intention probably is to keep the interactivity even when using the page as a desktop background, right?

Comment: Yup. That's about it

Comment: You can replace Finder with Safari. You can not have an interactive background by default. Cause your finder is already broken, try this: (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/is-there-a-way-to-replace-finder-altogether)