# Set ForkLift as default file viewer

Tags: macos, finder

Is there a way to set ForkLift as the default file viewer, to a degree? PathFinder somehow does this, see http://cocoatech.com/faqs#3, but how does it do this and could that option be set to redirect to ForkLift instead of PathFinder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Path Finder looks like it's modifying the "NSFileViewer" preference. You can set this manually from Terminal to point to ForkLift (I tried this, and it seems to work):

```
defaults write -g NSFileViewer -string com.binarynights.ForkLift2
```

(The `-g` sets this preference globally for all applications.)

However, be warned that the Path Finder website [lists some applications](http://cocoatech.com/docs/pf/default_file_viewer) that don't respect this setting, such as the Dock and Firefox.

Comment: The `-g` flag is equivalent to `NSGlobalDomain`. It simply writes the preference to the global domain, rather than to a specific domain.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! Seems to work well for the applications that do support it!

Comment: how do I revert to using Finder?

Comment: Try `defaults delete -g NSFileViewer`.

Comment: For ForkLift 3, the command is `defaults write -g NSFileViewer -string com.binarynights.ForkLift-3`

Comment: The "Default File Viewer" section in the docs have the instructions for ForkLift 3 : https://binarynights.com/manual  however when I download a file in Safari and reveal it in  Finder, it opens ForkLift but does not navigate to the Downloads folder. Anyone know how to have it do this?

Comment: How do I find the `com` string for other Finder-like apps (fman, marta etc.)?

Comment: That would be the CFBundleIdentifier in the app’s Info.plist.

Comment: @MathiasBynens what do you mean? What practical difference would leaving out `-g` make?

Answer (score 3):

Now as the ForkLift V3 came out, the new command should be:

```
defaults write -g NSFileViewer -string com.binarynights.ForkLift-3
```

At the same time, if you like to restore Finder to be the default file manager again, use:

```
defaults delete -g NSFileViewer
```

Answer (score 3):

From Forklift [official documentation](https://binarynights.com/manual):

> If you are using ForkLift from Setapp, paste this command instead:
>
> ```bsh
> defaults write -g NSFileViewer -string com.binarynights.forklift-setapp;
> defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType="public.folder";LSHandlerRoleAll="com.binarynights.ForkLift-3";}'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can change default file manager like this, but ForkLift or Transmit not work as expected, only Path Finder are

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6

from LaunchServices import LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType, kLSRolesViewer, LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme
from CoreFoundation import CFPreferencesCopyApplicationList, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost, CFPreferencesSetAppValue, CFPreferencesAppSynchronize

applicationBundleIdentifier = "com.cocoatech.PathFinder" #"com.panic.Transmit" #"com.binarynights.forklift2"

LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType("public.folder", kLSRolesViewer, applicationBundleIdentifier)
LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme("file:///", applicationBundleIdentifier)

applicationIDs = CFPreferencesCopyApplicationList(kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost)
for app_id in applicationIDs:
    CFPreferencesSetAppValue("NSFileViewer", applicationBundleIdentifier, app_id);
    CFPreferencesAppSynchronize(app_id);
```