# How do I set "Show in finder" to reveal location rather than open files (in default program)?

Tags: terminal, finder

I've had this problem for a while now on Yosemite. It all started when I tried to change Alfred to reveal files with forklift rather than finder. 
Since I couldn't get that to work i've reverted back to finder except now both Alfred and Chrome "show in finder" just opens the file instead of revealing in finder.

I've avoided fixing it for a while by using the terminal `open /path/to/folder` but that is super inefficient.

I couldn't find a similar question addressing this (frustrating) issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick <strike>(at least for now)</strike>

```
defaults delete -g NSFileViewer
```

I've restarted my machine several times and this appears to still be working

Answer (score 0):

here’s a fix:

Open the Terminal App and type/cut & paste the following:

```
$ sudo killall -KILL appleeventsd
```

Hit return, enter your password, and you should be all set.

Comment: I doubt this will work,this issue persist after reset and I think originates from following instructions [at this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45809/set-forklift-as-default-file-viewer)